# Formulario con imagen, ajax y phpmailer

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, phpmailer

Estoy intentando hacer una petición `POST` pero todos los datos se envían excepto la imagen.

¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

### JavaScript

```
$(function () {
$("#botonEnviar").click(function () {
    var nombre = document.getElementById("nombre").value;
    var correo = document.getElementById("correo").value;
    var mensaje = document.getElementById("mensaje").value;
    var telefono = document.getElementById("telefono").value;
    var foto = document.getElementById("foto");
    if (nombre == "") {
        $('#nombre').focus();
        $('#nombre').css('border-color', 'red');
        return false;
    } else if (correo == "") {
        $('#correo').focus();
        $('#correo').css('border-color', 'red');
        return false;
    } else if (mensaje == "") {
        $('#mensaje').focus();
        $('#mensaje').css('border-color', 'red');
        return false;
    } else if (telefono == "") {
        $('#telefono').focus();
        $('#telefono').css('border-color', 'red');
    } else {
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('nombre', nombre);
        formData.append('correo', correo);
        formData.append('mensaje', mensaje);
        formData.append('telefono', telefono);
        formData.append('foto', foto);
        $('input').val('');
        $('textarea').val('');
        $.ajax({
            url: 'php/procesar.php',
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function () {
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                $('.msg').text(thrownError);
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
});
});
```

### procesar.php

```
<?php
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$phpMailer = new PHPMailer;
$phpMailer->isSMTP();
$phpMailer->SMTPDebug = 2;
$phpMailer->Debugoutput = 'html';
$phpMailer->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$phpMailer->Port = 587;
$phpMailer->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$phpMailer->SMTPAuth = true;

/*Datos Formulario*/
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$correo = $_POST['correo'];
$mensaje = $_POST['mensaje'];
$telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
$fotoTmp = $_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'];
$fotoName = $_FILES['foto']['name'];

/*Cuenta Info*/
$phpMailer->Username = $info;
$phpMailer->Password =  $pswp;
$phpMailer->setFrom($info, $asunto);
$phpMailer->addAddress($correo, $nombre);
$phpMailer->addAddress($info, $nmb);

if(isset($_FILES['foto']) && $_FILES['foto']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK){
    $phpMailer->addAttachment($fotoTmp, $fotoName);
}

/*Mensaje para contacto*/
$phpMailer->isHTML(true);
$phpMailer->Subject = 'Asunto Mensaje';
$phpMailer->IsHTML(true);
$phpMailer->msgHTML(file_get_contents('mensaje.html'),dirname(__FILE__));

$phpMailer->AltBody = 'Cuerpo del Mensaje';

if (!$phpMailer->Send()) {
    echo "Error: ".$phpMailer->ErrorInfo;
}else{
    echo "Mensaje Enviado";
}    
?>
```

Comment: Lo pude solucionar quitando el dataType: 'JSON'. El problema ahora es que el correo me llega sin la imágen.

Comment: Te he puesto una solución adosando un controlador del evento `submit` del formulario. Si quieres hacerlo con el evento `click` del botón deberás facilitarme el código HTML del formulario, su `name`, su `id` o algo por el que acceder a él. No me gusta hacer búsquedas de la etiqueta `<form>` más cercana.

Comment: Por cierto @Johan, cambia el asunto de tu pregunta (dale a [EDITAR](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/102915/edit)) si lo que preguntas es otra cosa diferente a lo que pone el título o bien abre una pregunta nueva y cierra ésta. Gracias.

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo solucione con tus indicaciones.

Comment: De nada, un placer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes usar `new FormData(this);` para facilitar la tarea de crear los datos del formulario que serán enviados a través de XHR, acceder campo a campo funciona con los de valores de texto, pero no con las imágenes:

```
$(function () {
$("body").on("submit", "form", function () {
    var nombre = document.getElementById("nombre").value;
    var correo = document.getElementById("correo").value;
    var mensaje = document.getElementById("mensaje").value;
    var telefono = document.getElementById("telefono").value;
    var foto = document.getElementById("foto");
    if (nombre == "") {
        $('#nombre').focus();
        $('#nombre').css('border-color', 'red');
        return false;
    } else if (correo == "") {
        $('#correo').focus();
        $('#correo').css('border-color', 'red');
        return false;
    } else if (mensaje == "") {
        $('#mensaje').focus();
        $('#mensaje').css('border-color', 'red');
        return false;
    } else if (telefono == "") {
        $('#telefono').focus();
        $('#telefono').css('border-color', 'red');
    } else {
        var formData = new FormData(this);
        $('input').val('');
        $('textarea').val('');
        $.ajax({
            url: 'php/procesar.php',
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function () {
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                $('.msg').text(thrownError);
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
});
});
```

Deberás cambiar el `<button>` por un `<input type="submit">` para que te funcione el evento `submit`. En caso contrario dime cómo acceder a tu formulario o pon su HTML para que te diga cómo acceder a sus datos.